# How to get the content between 5th and 6th instance of a character

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract the directory between the 5th and 6th instance of `:` in each line below.

```
FTPAccount1:x:1001:10113:Ryan Murphy:/ftp/sub/Account1:/bin/bash
FTPAccount2:x:1002:10113:Ryan Murphy:/ftp/sub2/Account2:/bin/bash
```

I was thinking I would use a foreach loop to iterate through each line of my file and then use substring to grab the path between those characters. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: `('FTPAccount1:x:1001:10113:Ryan Murphy:/ftp/sub/Account1:/bin/bash' -split ':')[5]`

Comment: @Olaf Why did you post this as a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: Because I doubted that the answer meets the requirements for the intellectual level of creation on SO. ;-)